# Stop 'Music' app on tvOS from taking over screen when playing background music

Tags: swift, tvos

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to prevent the Music app from entirely taking over the screen and showing what's currently playing -- I want my app to remain showing but for the music to continue playing over the top of it.

I've set the idleTimerDisabled to be true, however this just prevents the screensaver from showing.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems to be fixed in tvOS 16.0

Answer (score 1):

Looks I got a combination of 2 things together to work:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true`
and
`myViewController.setNeedsFocusUpdate()` periodically